# Unable to play audio (.mid) files

Tags: c++, qt, midi, qt6, qtmultimedia

I need the program to play audio `.mid` files.

I'm using code from [Audio Overview](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/audiooverview.html) from the Qt Documentation:

```cpp
QMediaPlayer *player = new QMediaPlayer;
QAudioOutput *audioOutput = new QAudioOutput;

audioOutput->setDevice(QMediaDevices::defaultAudioOutput()); //Speaker(Realtek(R))Audio

player->setAudioOutput(audioOutput);
player->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("small_test.mid"));
player->play();
```

I **don't** hear any sound when I launch the program, also, after initializating `*player`, the terminal shows me the following:

```
Available HW decoding frameworks:
     d3d11va
     dxva2
Available HW encoding frameworks:
     d3d11va
     dxva2
```

I compiled the code on Windows. Maybe it is supposed to use another approach for midi files?

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow.  Since `.mid` files are not exactly audio files, this may require a different approach.